# Name of a specific hull

Tags: convex-hulls

Consider a set of points $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Let
$$H(S) = \\\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n, \forall a \in {\mathbb{R}^{+}}^n, \exists x \in S, \langle a,x-y\rangle\geq 0\}$$

This is the set of point for which are "below" at least one point in S under any linear projection with positive components.

In a same way the convex hull can be defined as the set of points which are less extremal than a point in S for any projection.

What can be said about this hull? Does it have a name? Known properties?

Comment: I doubt if it has a well known name. It is the smallest (closed) set of the form $A_x=\{x\}-Q$ such that $S \subset A_x$, where $Q=\{ x | x_k \ge 0 \}$ is the positive orthant.